# How to specify width of any inner element as a percentage of width of Body?

Tags: css, layout

When I apply width as a percentage to any inner element of a page, it applies the percentage to the width of its parent container.

**How to specify width of any inner element as a percentage of width of Body, instead of the default(percentage of width of parent container)?**

Additional Information: Depending on the device, the width of the Body will change. For devices above 1440px, it will have width as 1440px, else if width of device is less, then width of body will be 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't stylize your `<body>`.

Instead add a wrapper with a combo of **view port units** and **max-width**.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 1440px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Warkentien2 for replying. I'll implement & revert back.

Comment: As a related query, I was thinking why is there need to use multiple media queries for mobile devices? Cant we have a single media query for range of min-width & max-width and simply use vw, vh so that the page displays properly on all set of mobile devices?

Comment: Yes, you should always use the least amount of media queries possible. Here's a good read https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-100-correct-way-to-do-css-breakpoints-88d6a5ba1862. However, vh can behave a bit odd due to the browser's navigation bar that appears on and off.

Answer (score 2):

You can use viewport units.

```
<div class="parent"> /** Width:900px;  **/
      <div class="inner"> /** 100% of BODY, not of parent div **/

      </div>
   </div>

<style>
.parent {
background:red;
width:20px;
padding: 10px;
}


.inner {
background:green;
width: 100vw;
}
</style>
```

**or**

you can get width of the body using javascript and set its percent of width to other elements

**get width of body:**

```
document.body.clientHeight;
```

**set width in html element:**

```
document.getElementById('div_register').setAttribute("style","width:500px");
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahsan for replying. I'll implement & revert back.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want the width to be the width of the body then you can use viewport units.

1 vw is always 1% of the width of the viewport's initial containing block, which is usually the body.

So if you want something to be 20% of the body, you set it's width to `width: 20vw`.

Should work regardless of how far down in the DOM you nest this, and it works relative to whatever the screen size is when the page renders.

More on viewport units here https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Comment: Thanks @Josh for replying. I'll implement & revert back.